# No puedo instalar chromadb

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Estoy intentando instalar la librería de chromadb para python. Pero siempre me arroja este error:

```
ERROR: Cannot install chromadb==0.1.0, chromadb==0.2.0, chromadb==0.3.0, chromadb==0.3.1, chromadb==0.3.2, chromadb==0.3.25, chromadb==0.3.26, chromadb==0.3.27, chromadb==0.3.29, chromadb==0.4.0, chromadb==0.4.1, chromadb==0.4.10, chromadb==0.4.11, chromadb==0.4.12, chromadb==0.4.13, chromadb==0.4.14, chromadb==0.4.15, chromadb==0.4.16, chromadb==0.4.17, chromadb==0.4.18, chromadb==0.4.19, chromadb==0.4.2, chromadb==0.4.20, chromadb==0.4.21, chromadb==0.4.22, chromadb==0.4.3, chromadb==0.4.4, chromadb==0.4.5, chromadb==0.4.6, chromadb==0.4.7, chromadb==0.4.8 and chromadb==0.4.9 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    chromadb 0.4.22 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.21 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.20 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.19 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.18 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.17 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.16 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.15 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.14 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.13 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.12 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.11 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.10 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.9 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.8 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.7 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.6 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.5 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.4 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.3 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.2 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.1 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.4.0 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.3.29 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.3.27 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.3.26 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.3.25 depends on onnxruntime>=1.14.1
    chromadb 0.3.2 depends on numpy~=1.21.6
    chromadb 0.3.1 depends on numpy~=1.21.6
    chromadb 0.3.0 depends on numpy~=1.21.6
    chromadb 0.2.0 depends on numpy~=1.21.6
    chromadb 0.1.0 depends on numpy~=1.21.6

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

He intentado instalar versiones anteriores, pero no funciona. Quiero intentar lo que me recomienda la terminal de remover las versiones de paquetes, pero no sé como hacerlo. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradecería.

Comment: ¿En que versión de Python intentas instalarlo? Si es Python 3.12: https://github.com/chroma-core/chroma/issues/1410. Por ahora no es compatible con Python3.12, a la espera de que todas las dependencias que necesita (que son bastantes por cierto) estén disponibles para esta versión de Python. Para usarlo ahora tendrás que  instalar Python 3.11, en el cual no deberías tener problemas.

Comment: @FJSevilla Ay, hermano, me compré un pc nuevo en diciempre y a raiz de eso instalé la última versión de python y no ha hecho sino darme problemas... C'est la vie

Comment: El problema de usar la versión mas reciente de Python es que algunos paquetes aun no se han portado para funcionar con dicha versión. No obstante, puedes tener varias versiones de Python instaladas y cuantos entornos virtuales quieras (siempre es recomendable tener cada proyecto con su venv). En windows es simplemente instalarla y especificar el interprete a usar luego, en Linux es siempre recomendable dejar sin tocar la instalación de Python del sistema, yo suelo usar [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) para manejar múltiples versiones comodamente, también vale para MacOS.

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir a la pregunta una explicación de cómo exáctamente estás instalando este paquete? ¿Usas algún entorno virtual? ¿Por qué intenta instalar tantas versiones?